# "Смерть застигла" или "смерть настигла"?

Tags: семантика, фразеология

В телефильме о гибели города Помпеи голос за кадром произносит слова "смерть застигла жителей города...". Учитывая тот факт, что многие горожане успели спастись, своевременно покинув город, а другие (не такие расторопные) с опозданием пытались уйти из Помпей или прятались от раскалённого вулканического пепла в домах, не было бы более правильным употребление в данном случае слов "смерть настигла жителей города..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Важно, что в том предложении на месте многоточия: если сказано, что *врасплох* или ***за*** каким-то занятием, то так сказать можно (= при каких обстоятельствах "настигла"). "Застигнуть" - понятие относительное и требует такой дополнительной оговорки. Если её нет, то правильно "**настигла**" или "**постигла**" (смотря насколько неожиданно).

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander!

Answer (score 1):

**ПОСТИЧЬ.** Можно сказать:Семью постигло горе. Меня постигло несчастье. Неудача постигла нас. Его постигло жестокое разочарование. Смерть постигла их - это нейтральный вариант со значением "случилась", например: "Замечательно, что смерть **постигла** графа Толя именно в день Георгия Победоносца, столько раз покровительствовавшего ему на поле брани".

**НАСТИЧЬ.**  Настичь - это значит нагнать/догнать. Мы говорим: дождь настиг нас в лесу. Буря настигла лодку далеко от берега. Мы ожидали, что пойдет дождь (собрались тучи), и он пошел, когда мы были в лесу.

Так говорят **о неизбежном или ожидаемом событии**, в том числе о смерти, поэтому **этот вариант практически не отличается от первого:** "Смерть **настигла** поэта на Кавказе". "А через пять дней смерть **настигла** и самого монарха". "Смерть **настигла** Лилию Ивановну в расцвете творческих сил, в разгаре научной и литературной работы".

**ЗАСТИЧЬ.** Так можно сказать о событии, **которого мы не ожидали**: ночью нас застигла гроза. **И поэтому о жителях Помпеи говорят: смерть застигла их.** Также: "Они не сделали духовного завещания… Смерть **застигла** их слишком внезапно".

Comment: Спасибо, Sergey!

Answer (score 1):

Стилистически лучше "настигла". Это хорошо передает ощущение *настигшей* неприятности, а до того погони, а "застигла" - не так.

А если важен момент, когда именно, то "застигла" - в момент случайной неожиданной встречи.

Comment: Так вроде тут "застигла" как раз и уместно, если принять, что говорящему важен эффект неожиданности?! А так - да, с оценкой стилистики могу в основном согласиться. Да она и в словарях есть.

Comment: Да, и пишите чуть более подробно. Ответы новичков приходится проверять опытным пользователям, особенно если они короткие.

Comment: С п а с и б о !